# How to send Payload Message Using DevShock Smpp

Tags: c#, smpp

In one of old projects I have done SMSC integration with DevShock.Smpp. Now Support for this tool is no longer available and I came across a situation where I have to send PayLoad SMS.

Below is my code

```
private static SmppSubmitSmRes Sendbin(byte[] bbin, bool multiMsg, string aNumber, string bNumber, bool isUniCode, long messageType, SmppConnection _mySmppClient)
    {
        SmppSubmitSmReq.BodyPdu reqSubmitSm = new SmppSubmitSmReq.BodyPdu
        {
            EsmClass = multiMsg ? new BitBuilder(Convert.ToByte(0x40)) : new BitBuilder(Convert.ToByte(0x0))
        };

        //Dim ResSubmit_Sm As SmppSubmitSmRes
        // ReqSubmit_Sm.ShortMessage.SetValue(bbin)
        //if it is unicode use 0x08 like for arabic or other unicode lang.
        if (isUniCode)
        {
            reqSubmitSm.ShortMessage.DataCoding = messageType == 1 ? SmppDataCoding.FromValue(24) : SmppDataCoding.Unicode;
            //reqSubmitSm.ShortMessage.DataCoding = SmppDataCoding.Unicode;
            //.FromValue(CByte(&H8))
            reqSubmitSm.SourceAddressNpi = new BitBuilder(1).Value;
        }
        else
        {
            reqSubmitSm.SourceAddressNpi = Convert.ToByte(0);
            reqSubmitSm.ShortMessage.DataCoding = SmppDataCoding.Default;
            reqSubmitSm.ShortMessage.DataCoding = messageType == 1 ? SmppDataCoding.FromValue(240) : SmppDataCoding.Default;
        }
        if (IsNumeric(aNumber))
        {
            reqSubmitSm.SourceAddressTon = isUniCode ? new BitBuilder(2).Value : (byte)0;
        }
        else
        {
            reqSubmitSm.SourceAddressTon = Convert.ToByte(5);
        }
        reqSubmitSm.DestinationAddressTon = Convert.ToByte(1);
        reqSubmitSm.DestinationAddressNpi = Convert.ToByte(1);
        reqSubmitSm.DestinationAddress = bNumber;
        reqSubmitSm.SourceAddress = aNumber;
        reqSubmitSm.ShortMessage.Value = bbin;
        reqSubmitSm.SourceAddress = aNumber;

        if (true)//delivery
        {
            reqSubmitSm.RegisteredDelivery = new BitBuilder(1);
        }
        var submitResponse = _mySmppClient.SubmitSm(new SmppSubmitSmReq(reqSubmitSm));
        return submitResponse;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can, switch and use INTELAB
great solution with great support on there forum
[inetlab support](https://inetlab.com/support/)